# Rails and sqlite 3 in different locations - problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm working with an Agile Web Development book to learn Rails, and it's using sqlite 3 for a database. On my Mac Snowleopard system  sqlite3 is installed in

```
/opt/local/bin/sqlite3
```

whereas the other necessary components are all

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/irb
/usr/bin/gem
/usr/bin/rake
```

Will this create a problem? If so, how can I fix the problem in advance?  If it involves doing something with the PATH variable, can you please provide detailed instructions how to fix it.

Thanks from a newbie...

UPDATE

**This is my current bash profile**

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

## MacPorts Installer addition on 2011-09-20_at_01:30:15: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

## Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

Comment: no, i haven't. I'm trying to understand PATHs now, so if it doesn't work, I will have an idea. Does sqlite3 have to be in the same location?

Comment: NO. Just try it first. If it doesn't work then ask for help.

Comment: @thomasfedb   Am I not allowed to ask questions about PATHs here in the abstract without trying it?  If you don't want to help, then don't bother answering, but seriously quit the bitching...if I try it and it doesn't work, there might be multiple reasons why it doesn't work and then the problem will be more difficult to solve..

Comment: Michael, calm down, easy there. I'm not "bitching". I'm just pointing out that the best way to work out if something works is to try. If you have a problem then we'll have something more solid to work from, rather than a hypothetical problem that may or may not exist.

Comment: o.k., sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as everything's in the PATH, it will be fine.

Comment: to be honest, as a newbie, i have no idea about any of this, but I see that MacPorts has added an "export" line that includes the location for sqlite3, but i'm wondering if that export line needs to be connected to the already existing "export" line in the bash_profile...

Comment: See this bit `export PATH=/opt/local/bin`. That means that any file in that directory will be in your PATH. That's where the sqlite file is, so it will be in your path, and should work just fine.